Is my reasoning about KKT conditions correct?
Given an optimization problem of the form
\begin{align*}
\min c^Tx \text{ s.t. } h_1(x) = 0, h_2(x)=0
\end{align*}
Where $h_1$ is affine linear and $h_2$ is a convex function.
In order to solve this problem I was looking at the KKT-conditions and for my specific problem those have a unique solution $x^*$.
Since every global optimum satisfies the KKT-conditions and this is the only point satisfying those, $x^*$ must be an optimum. BUT there might exist other optimal points that result in the same optimal value which I have not found.

Do you really have a convex problem? In this case, the functions $h_i$ have to be affine and your problem is a linear problem.

No, $h_2$ is only a convex function. Sorry, I messed up the definition. I will correct it.

This reasoning is not correct. There might be global minima that are not KKT points.
Consider the problem $\min f(x)$ subject to $h_1(x)=0$, $h_2(x)=0$ with $f(x)=x$, $h_1=0$ and
$$
h_2(x) = \begin{cases} (x+1)^2 & \text{ if } x<-1\\
0 & \text{ if } -1\le x <1\\
(x-1)^2 & \text{ if } 1<x.
\end{cases}.
$$
Then $x^*=-1$ is the global minimum with $f'(x^*)\ne0$ and $h_1'(x^*)=h_2'(x^*)=0$. Hence $x^*$ is not a KKT point.

Note that the constraint $h_2(x)=0$ does not imply that the set of feasible points is convex.

Hello Thank you very much! I see. I think the issue is that I am assuming that the KKT - conditions are necessary.
But: If for example at my unique point $x^$ which satisfies the KKT conditions, I check for LICQ, i.e. I compute $\nabla h_1(x^), \nabla h_2(x^*)$, verify that those are linearly independent and that $h_i$ is differentiable, then I have necessity and my reasoning would be correct?

No. There still can be a global minimum that is no KKT point.

Ah yes, I see. Because I can only be sure to have found a local optimum?
